# Click effect not smooth

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am having a problem with the smoothness of my app animation.
I have 20 buttons on this page. If I press any of the buttons, the click effect is not running smoothly. The frame rate is very low. Is there any problem with the code or it is a bug?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Are you running your application in debug mode?

Comment: I have tried both in debug and release mode..
but the frame rate is almost the same.

Comment: Can you post the code please?

Comment: Here is the code   https://pastebin.com/cJnXER5D

Comment: Seems to be a problem with your device. Runs smoothly on mine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly streamlined version of your button builder method that properly contains the ink effect in the rounded rectangle shape, but that should not impact performance. Performance-wise, there is nothing wrong with your code.

```
Widget buildMaterialButton() {
  return Expanded(
    child: RawMaterialButton(
      fillColor: Colors.blueGrey,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0)),
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Text("1"),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```